# Webi document export to pdf

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Is it possible to change the default Initial view in a adobe document to always show Bookmarks pane, whenever any adobe document is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the options in the Document properties dialog. Adjust them and resave the document.